# How to populating Modified Preorder Tree Traversal data into Java tree object?

Tags: java, php, tree, populate, mptt

I have the following table with a *MPTT* structure :

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menus (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  lft int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  rght int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  module_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  module_controller_name varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  module_action_name varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  alias varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO menus (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rght`, `module_name`,    
`module_controller_name`, `module_action_name`, `alias`) VALUES (1, NULL, 1, 14,  
'Root', '', '', 'Root'),
(2, 1, 2, 7, 'Toolbox', '', '', 'Toolbox'),
(3, 2, 5, 6, 'Menu Manajemen', 'menus', 'index', 'MenuManajemenz'),
(4, 2, 3, 4, 'Hak Akses Manajemen', 'access_rights', 'index', 'HakAksesManajemen'),
(5, 1, 8, 13, 'Accounts', '', '', 'Accounts'),
(6, 5, 9, 10, 'Users', 'users', 'index', 'Users'),
(7, 5, 11, 12, 'Groups', 'groups', 'index', 'Groups');
```

In *CakePHP* I can make the following data structure :

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Menu] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [lft] => 2
                    [rght] => 7
                    [module_name] => Toolbox
                    [module_controller_name] => 
                    [module_action_name] => 
                    [alias] => Toolbox
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Menu] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [lft] => 3
                                    [rght] => 4
                                    [module_name] => Hak Akses Manajemen
                                    [module_controller_name] => access_rights
                                    [module_action_name] => index
                                    [alias] => HakAksesManajemen
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Menu] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [lft] => 5
                                    [rght] => 6
                                    [module_name] => Menu Manajemen
                                    [module_controller_name] => menus
                                    [module_action_name] => index
                                    [alias] => MenuManajemenz
                                )

                             [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                 )

         )
    )
```

The problem is how can I populate *MPTT* data structure in *Java*, using a *Java* tree class. Yes, I know *Java* can not have dynamic array like in *PHP*, in *Java* you have to use class *Model*.

My Model class looks like this:

```java
public class Menu {
    private String moduleName;
    private String moduleControllerName;
    private String moduleActionName;
    private String alias;

    public String getModuleName() {
        return moduleName;
    }

    public void setModuleName(String moduleName) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    public String getModuleControllerName() {
        return moduleControllerName;
    }

    public void setModuleControllerName(String moduleControllerName) {
        this.moduleControllerName = moduleControllerName;
    }

    public String getModuleActionName() {
        return moduleActionName;
    }

    public void setModuleActionName(String moduleActionName) {
        this.moduleActionName = moduleActionName;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

I find it very confusing and I don't know any way on how to do it. Data that comes from database is populated to a *Java* tree object. I don't know what to do, I don't know how to populate it completely. I am using [*Vivin's GenericTree* Java class](http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java)

I think i need data querying strategy, is it need a recursive function to retrieve all data from database? I think it takes two steps : 1. Querying the data, 2. Populate all data to tree object.

Comment: @Bob ~ hey Bob :) what you edit? thank you for reviewing my question. if u know the solution, please help Bob :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not really need a generic tree data structure for this. Consider the following example:

```
private static final class Menu {
    private Menu parent;
    private List<Menu> children;

    private String moduleName;
    private String moduleControllerName;
    private String moduleActionName;
    private String alias;
}
```

(getters/setters ommited for conciseness)

The `parent` field helps you set the parent menu and can be null for the root menu.

Add the Children menu to the `children` field.

With this you will be able to capture the needs of your hierarchical menu I hope.

Now to build the query supposing you have a result set `rs`:

```
Menu menu;

while (rs.hasNext()) {
    if (rs.get("parent_id") == null) {
        // it s the root
        menu = new Menu(rs.get("id"), /* etc... */);
    } else {
        menu = findMenuById(menu, rs.get("parent_id"));
        menu.addChild(new Menu(rs.get("id"), /* etc... */));
}
```

as for find `findMenuById` it could be something like:

```
private Menu findMenuById(Menu menu, Long id) {
    if (menu.getId() == id) return menu;
    for (Menu childMenu : menu.getChildren()) {
        Menu found = findMenuById(childMenu, id);
        if (found != null) return found;
    }
    return null;
}
```

#### edit

Here is a custom working implementation I made. I inserted your menu in the database and use result set. I should be almost the same with the custom abstraction of yours.

```
Menu root = null;
        Map<Integer, Menu> menus = new HashMap<Integer, Menu>();

        final Database databaseConnection = Database.createConnection("test", "root", "");
        final ResultSet rs = databaseConnection.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test.menus;");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            final Menu menu = new Menu(rs.getInt("id"))
                .setAlias(rs.getString("alias"))
                .setModuleName(rs.getString("module_name"));

            final Integer parentId = rs.getInt("parent_id");
            if (root == null && parentId == 0) {
                root = menu;
            } else {
                menus.get(parentId).addSubMenu(menu);
            }

            menus.put(menu.getId(), menu);
        }

        rootMenu = root;

        databaseConnection.closeConnection();
```

`Note 1`: I used an `HashMap` to store the menus that are not attached to the root yet.

`Note 2`: This implementation wont work if there are more than one root menu.

Comment: Thank you. 
But How the SQL Query structure for this problem? is it need a recursive function to retrieve all data from database? I don't know any clue about it. How to detect if a row is a parent? then?

Comment: Hmmm..i think i need the data querying strategy. Ahhh hard to say.. :(

Comment: Thank you ph. I will try ur solution. And tommorow i will comeback again. thx u very much

Comment: Halo i've try your solution but i still can't make it working :( i've edit my question to explain what i have done. I am sorry, this is my first time using stackoverflow.

Comment: this is what i've done. But i still can not make it working :(
http://pastie.org/5072156 and http://pastie.org/5072174 . Still error returning NULL. The i am not sure the tree is populated.

here http://pastie.org/5072174 my data is encapsuled List<Exploration> , i am using my company database abstraction library. So i am not fetch my data using 
    while (rs.hasNext()) {

Comment: where do you have your null? any information would be helpfull, like a stacktrace for example

Comment: don't know what to do i am puzzled

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add a `private Menu menu;` instance variable so that you can model a tree structure

Answer (score 0):

It might be valuable for you to check this Java JPA implementation of MPTT.
The demo in the source code could give ideas how to model your entity, as well as populating the tree.

https://github.com/hacker-works/mptt-jpa